# Server side debounce

Tags: node.js, debouncing

I have a small Node/Express API with a mongodb and socket.io, where i handle incoming request. I would like to create some kind of "debounce function", to check whether the server did not receive any request for a timeframe and then emit a message to update the connected clients.

Is there an easy way to make a function shared/global, so different processes can pick them up? Or any other way to install a countdown, that other requests can reset?